# Job Notes in a custom php web app not showing

Tags: php

Hoping some of you out there are great with php!

Basically the guy who made this is MIA so I can't ask him what I need to do to fix the problem we are having.

**Background:**
We are a locksmith company that uses a custom web app to inform our locksmiths on the road when they have a new job. This web app also does a few extra things like providing gps location, time taken at the job and the ability to have save signature from the client upon work completion.

**Problem:**
The app works by picking up an email sent from our account management application called E3, the email (example: http://cl.ly/image/2E433O330T0N) is read by this web app, parsed into both an email and a web page and sent to the locksmith to view his new job. When the locksmith arrives at the web page on his phone (example: http://cl.ly/image/0P1I0R0h0O3K), he can see the job details including the Name, address and contact details for the client. The problem is though, because Job Notes isn't assigned a heading in the original email the code has to work out where Job Notes is located, this is the part that has the problem as the web app is no longer showing the data in Job Notes. Job Notes is important because it tells the locksmith what he needs to fix. This worked previously but has now just stopped working and we aren't sure why.

How the data is transferred to the web app is very interesting, instead of having a database to store data to, it is put in the address bar and then the webpage interprets the code and formats it into the page.

For example, this is how the current link looks (data taken out, replaced with xxxxxxx):

> http://www.xxxxxxx.com/apps/xxxxxx/on-my-way?**client**=xxxxxx&**company**=xxxxxx&**mobile**=xxxxxxx&**phone**=xxxxxxx&**contact**=xxxxxxxx&**addressData**=Array&**addressIndex**=3&**streetAddress**=xxxxxxxxx&**addressLocality**=xxxxxxxx&**postcode**=xxxxxxx&**city**=xxxxxxx&**clientEmail**=&**jobDate**=11/22/2012&**jobTime**=1:30:00%20PM&**jobID**=xxxxxx&**jobAMPM**=PM&**adminEmail**=xxxxxxx&**noreplyEmail**=xxxxxxxxxx&**companyPhone**=xxxxxxxx&**staffEmail**=xxxxxxxx&**staffName**=xxxxxxx&**staffPhone**=xxxxxxxx

Previously, when working, this link had a jobNotes field added:

> http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/apps/xxxxxxxx/on-my-way?**client**=xxxxxxxx&**company**=xxxxxxxx&**mobile**=xxxxxxxx&**phone**=&**contact**=xxxxxxxx&**addressData**=Array&**addressIndex**=4&**streetAddress**=xxxxxxxx&**addressLocality**=xxxxxxxx&**postcode**=xxxxxxxx&**city**=xxxxxxxx&**clientEmail**=xxxxxxxx&***jobNotes*=Quote%20on%20installing%20new%20keying%20system%0A%0AAlso%20would%20like%20a%20Quote%20on%20Install%20CCTV%0A%0ASub%20Total%3A%202%2C236.36%0AGST%3A%20223.64%0ATotal%3A%202%2C460.00%0A%0AMISC&**jobDate***=11/19/2012*&**jobTime**=2:00:00%20PM&**jobID**=xxxxxxxx&**jobAMPM**=PM&**adminEmail**=xxxxxxxx&**noreplyEmail**=xxxxxxxx&**companyPhone**=xxxxxxxx&**staffEmail**=xxxxxxxx&**staffName**=xxxxxxxx&**staffPhone**=xxxxxxxx

**The code:**

This is an extract from e3-parser.php, the main file that translates the data from the e3 email to the web app.

```
    // Job notes
  if ($this->clientEmail) {

// REMOVED NOW THAT EMAIL IS BEING PUT ON THIRD LINE OF ADDRESS
//   // If customer email present grab everything after it save it as job notes
//   preg_match("/$this->clientEmail[^-]+/",$e3Output,$matches);
//   $result = implode("",$matches);
//   $notes  = trim(str_replace($this->clientEmail,'',$result));
//   $this->jobNotes = rawurlencode($notes);
// } else {

    // Fall back to grabbing everything after the time
    preg_match("/AM[^-]+/",$e3Output,$matchesAM);
    preg_match("/PM[^-]+/",$e3Output,$matchesPM);
    $resultAM = implode("",$matchesAM);
    $resultPM = implode("",$matchesPM);    
    $notes  = trim(str_replace('AM','',$resultAM) . str_replace('PM','',$resultPM));
    $this->jobNotes = rawurlencode($notes);
  }
```

Question here is, does it successfully grab the data listed after the **Required Time** field? (example email that it's reading from: `http://cl.ly/image/2E433O330T0N`)

Here is the code that places the parsed data into the web page:

```
// Create job link
$url      = $e3->create_job_url('http://www.prvgroup.com.au/apps/jobbook/on-my-way?');  
$linkName = "View job details";
$href     = '<a class="btn btn-small" href="' . $url . '&staffEmail=' . $staff-    >staffEmail . '&staffName=' . $staff->staffName . '&staffPhone=' . $staff->staffPhone . '">' . $linkName . '</a>';
```

This is sent to the locksmith via email informing him of his new job on the clickable link "View job details". The link is impregnated with the data needed. However from the looks of it the data for jobNotes isn't there. My backups of this code display the exact same thing here when the code was displaying jobNotes so I'm not exactly sure how it is putting that field in.

If you got this far, well done! I hope I was clear enough with what the issue is but if you need anymore clarification, just ask!

Cheers,
Marc

Comment: This is a tough project to diagnose using the details provided.  If I had to take a guess I would say there is a transfer issue or a variable that has been mis-named.  I will say that using a URL rewrite method is probably not the best way to handle this type of transaction, but I am sure it will be easier to diagnose this issue than rewrite the project.  From the top URL you are missing the job notes and it would make sense that they cannot be displayed on the page since that variable does not exist in the URL.  I am happy to assist if you are willing to share a bit more code.

Comment: Thanks Jammin, I would love to just go ahead and post the complete code here but I fear repercussions from my superiors if I do that. Is there a way to give you it without making it publicly available? via email perhaps?

Comment: Add an @ gmail.com to my username.  I will take a look and see if anything jumps out at me.

Comment: Done. Thanks so much for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through your code you are only running the preg_match if there is a clientEmail.  From the sample emails above it does not look like you are ever executing this code because there is no client email or it is not found using the preg_match.  The specific location to look into is on line 113 of the e3-parser.php file.  You will see this:

```
if($this->clientEmail) 
{
    //matching code here.
}
```

on line 109 and 110 you are looking for an email address and either not finding one or it is looking in the wrong location.  At any rate, you should execute this code regardless of whether there is an email address or not.  The notes must be set for later use, right now nothing is being set.  Removing this if statement should resolve your issue.

Comment: That's it! The first one didn't have any client email filled in so there was no notes processed because of the IF statement. Genius! Thanks so much Jammin!

Comment: Glad I could help out!  In case you were worried, I have deleted your code as well.